# Snowflake merge into update is not working after binding a JSON object, but it works when tested with simple update query

Tags: sql, merge, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to merge some data from a source to a target table by binding a JSON object to the query.

The query is within a JavaScript stored procedure:

```
var merge_data = "MERGE INTO UNPIVOTED_DATA UD "+
          "USING (SELECT KEY AS TABLE_COL, VALUE AS TABLE_COL_VAL from lateral flatten(input => parse_json(?))) ST "+
          "ON (ST.TABLE_COL = UD.TABLE_FIELD_NAME) "+
          "WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET UD.ODK_FIELD_NAME = ST.TABLE_COL_VAL";
var merge_data_stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: merge_data, binds: [JSON.stringify(full_table_fields_array)]});
var merge_data_rs = merge_data_stmt.execute();
merge_data_rs.next();
return merge_data_rs;
```

The JSON is having the following shape:

var a = {"field_name1": "field/name1", "something_else": "something/else"};

[here](https://jsfiddle.net/q18so765/) is a small extract of the full JSON Object.

If I test the `flatten` query by itself it will work just fine and flatten the array:

```
SELECT KEY AS TABLE_COL, VALUE AS TABLE_COL_VAL from lateral flatten(input => parse_json(?))
```

I think the problem is within the `JSON.stringify` ?

Comment: I tested and as I see, there is nothing wrong with JSON.stringify. You said that the SELECT query works, so the issue should be related with the MERGE SQL. Can you share the error you get?

Comment: There is no errors at all. Is it because there is no physical at all out of flatten result ?

Comment: Alim, as I see, you flatten JSON to columns, and then find these field names in table, but your sample JSON has a very long field names. Have you tried to run the MERGE command with that sample JSON on UI?

Comment: Yeah and it worked on the test sample.